# takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given; Combined String as Argument

Tags: python, binance

i´m pretty new to python and even after searching the inet, i don´t understand what´s wrong here.
For using the Binance API, i need the Command like this: `client.get_order_book(symbol = 'ETHBTC')`

As the symbol is dynamic, i tried

```
x1 = 'symbol = '
x2 = symbols[0].get('symbol')       #Output: ETHBTC
x = x1 + "'" + x2 + "'"
print(x)                            #Output: symbol = 'ETHBTC'
```

but when i call

```
client.get_order_book(x)
```

it draws the error:

> TypeError: get_order_book() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were
>   given

This is the rest of the Code:

```
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

symbols = client.get_ticker()
print(symbols[0].get('symbol'))  #Output ETHBTC

y = len(symbols)
for i in range(y):
    x1 = 'symbol = '
    x2 = symbols[i].get('symbol')
    x = x1 + "'" + x2 + "'"
    print(x)  #Output: symbol = 'ETHBTC'
    print(client.get_order_book(x))
```

i read a lot about `self`, but i do not understand, where and how it has to be used here?!

Comment: i´m using this framwork: https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance

Comment: Are you trying to construct the keyword argument as a string? That's not going to work.

Comment: ^ This. Also ```self``` is used only inside class object. You don't need it on your main python file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`x` is the literal string `symbol='ETHBTC'`, not a "saved" keyword argument.
Your attempted call is equivalent to

```
client.get_order_book("symbol='ETHBTC'"),
```

but this method doesn't take any positional arguments (aside from `self`). Here's the [signature](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/blob/master/binance/client.py#L456):

```
def get_order_book(self, **params):
```

To prepackage keyword arguments and simulate

```
client.get_order_book(symbol='ETHBTC')
```

you need a `dict` to encapsulate the keyword argument.

```
x = {'symbol': 'ETHBTC'}
client.get_order_book(**x)
```

Comment: x = {'symbol': symbols[i].get('symbol')}
depth = client.get_order_book(**x) works perfectly :)
Thank u very much!

Answer (score -1):

method `get_order_book` dont wait any parameters when it called.
WHen you initiate instance of class by  comand client = Client() `self` is gets into all not `staticmethod`s by default as argument to refer to instance of class inside the method. You should point that method `get_order_book` gets a parameter:

```
class Client(object):
    ...
    def get_order_book(self, symbol):
        # do something with symbol
```

or if you don't need refer to instance of class in method:

```
class Client(object):
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def get_order_book(symbol):
        # do something with symbol
```

and if you want to args in method be predefined (vals by default) you should use:

```
...
def get_order_book(self, symbol="some_default_symbol"):
    ...
    print(symbol)    # will print "some_default_symbol"
```

Comment: `get_order_book` is a predefined method that takes an optional `symbol` keyword argument, not something the OP is defining.